# How can I find where a dialect word come from?

Tags: topolect

I often come across words like this in a dictionary:

> 肚皮 <方> 腹部; 肚子 (dù·zi)。

I would like to know if there's a way (a website or a dictionary or whatever other way instead of asking someone) where I can search what 方言 the word came from and what is its relevance to *putonghua* (if it's used at all and its acceptance, etc).

Comment: [English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%82%9A%E7%9A%AE) has your particular query.

Comment: It's really cool that it has a dialectal map showing where each variety is used. How can I know how widely is its usage and acceptance in putonghua, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There ARE dialect dictionaries available in this country, for example:
[现代汉语方言大词典](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8E%B0%E4%BB%A3%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E5%A4%A7%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/7763435)
But it includes 41(!) volumes and may cost you more than $300.

Comment: Holy sh*! I hope that's RMB. lol